# How can I retrieve binary data from sql with c#?

Tags: c#

I retrieved the data that I saved in a filestream column as an example the
below code, and got it into memory stream or byte array. How can I open it
with its default?

OS application like opening a photo with photo manager or word document with
MS Word ? Normally I use the Process.Start command **but it doesn't work with
memorystream or byte array so how can this be done ?**

```
 public DataTable RetriveFile(int Code)
        {
            mydbms d = new mydbms();
            DataTable dt;


           String com2 = "select * from Matn_Naame where Code=" + Code + ";";
           dt = d.executeselectsql(com2);


            return dt;
        }
{
Letter_Manager L_M = new Letter_Manager();
            Byte[] b;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = L_M.RetriveFile(6);

            b=(Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["fileContent"];
            path = dt.Rows[0]["Path"].ToString();

                 MemoryStream Memory = new MemoryStream(b);
                 Memory.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
//??????????????????**?for open and show file**
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to save the data to a temporary file. A temporary filename is available by calling `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()`. You can then simply use a `FileStream` to save to that path, and as you mentioned, `Process.Start` to launch the default application.

Comment: Please Help
i have blow code:
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                 
            Path.GetTempFileName();
                 fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                 
            fs.Flush();
                 fs.Close();
i dont now satrt fs
if Process.Start(fs.Name)?
but it start app with same path that exit not from sql

Comment: but it start file with same path that exist not from  read byte from sql

Comment: This is a very useful answer. I didn't even know the existance of such a method. Thanks!

Comment: @Mary: You should be assigning `path = Path.GetTempFileName();` and then use `Process.Start(path)`.

Comment: @Mary: If you have everything working now, would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the convenient [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) method which writes a byte array directly to the file name specified.

```
var fileName = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), "txt");
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, b);
Process.Start(fileName);
```

Note that in my example I have assumed that you are dealing with plain text data that you wish to open with the default text editor.

Windows will not know what application to launch this file unless you give it a meaningful extension. You either have to know the format of the data upfront so you can append the correct extension or you'll need to use a library that can guess what kind of data it is such as the excellent [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) file identification tool.

Comment: thanx for answer but
when run this codes one temp file with tmp extention creat
and error occurd:
No application is associated with the specified file for this operation
please help me
thanx

Comment: See the amendment to my answer regarding file extensions.

Comment: my extetention files is txt or doc or docx
where i append my extetion to tempfile?

Comment: I have changed the code so that the temp file extension is "txt". You still need some way to determine if you're dealing with plain text or an MS Word document.

Comment: very thanx for your HElp
Thanxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx :-)

Comment: It has been a while now that I look for a way not to hardly create a generated PDF file on the HDD, but simply persist it throguh a MemoryStream or so and then show it to the user. I shall change my code in order to allow me to use temporary files this way. As for working comfortably with the derived objects of Stream, I wasn't sure how to do it. Thanks!